# Did the Hydra lose its head because of me?

Tags: dragons-dogma-dark-arisen

I fought the Hydra at the encampment early in the game.  While my Pawns were attacking, I instinctively ran around behind and climbed up to get to the head.  I stopped when I noticed this bulging part at the neck. Of course I decided to hack away at it.

The next thing I knew, there was a cutscene where the head I was attacking flew off having been severed. I am wondering, is this scene scripted to show a severed head or did it get severed because I did it? (As such if should I fight it again I should do the same?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that scene always plays.  The severed head leads into the next mission.

On a side note, climbing on big monsters is usually one of the best ways to take them down (except for mage/sorcerer).  So you'll get to do that a lot more ^^